# Does an entire modular form (for $\operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)$) that is not a cusp form vanish at *any* cusp?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Let $M_k$ be the space of entire modular forms for the modular group and $S_k$ the subspace of cusp forms. Let $f \in M_k \setminus S_k$.

> Does $f$ vanish at any element of $\Bbb Q \cup \lbrace \infty\rbrace$?

I understand that the modular group acts transitively on $\Bbb Q \cup \{\infty\}$. Does this mean that $f$ cannot have any rational or $\infty$ as a zero?

Let $s \in \Bbb Q \cup \{\infty\}$, let $\gamma \in \operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)$ such that $\gamma\infty = s$ and suppose $f(s) = 0$. Then also $f(\infty) = 0$, since $0 = f(s) = j_\gamma(\infty)^{k}f(\infty)$. Since I can always reach $\infty$ by acting with some $\gamma$, every element of $\Bbb Q \cup \{\infty\}$ is going to be a zero of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$. Using the transformation law and expanding $f$ as a Fourier series, we have
$$\frac{f\left(\frac{a\tau + b}{c \tau + d}\right)}{(c\tau + d)^k} = f(\tau) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_ne^{2\pi i\tau n}.$$
Then
$$\lim_{\textrm{Im}(\tau) \to \infty}\frac{f\left(\frac{a\tau + b}{c \tau + d}\right)}{(c\tau + d)^k} = a_0 \neq 0.$$
On the other hand, since $\frac{a\tau + b}{c\tau + d} \to s$ as $\textrm{Im}(\tau) \to \infty$, if $\lim_{\tau \to s}f(\tau) = 0$ then the above limit would be $0$.